# Kafka Kraft cluster + View metadata not working properly

Tags: linux, apache-kafka

we installed Kafka Kraft cluster version 3.5 on 3 VM RHEL Linux machines  ( as part of lab testing )

Kafka Kraft cluster is working well and all brokers are up and running and controllers are running as well

the configuration for controllers and brokers are set  on following path:

```
/home/controller_home/kafka_2.13-3.5.1/config/kraft/controller.properties
/home/broker_home/kafka_2.13-3.5.1/config/kraft/broker.properties
```

we successfully created topics and we can view the topics by kafka cli as well

**the last thing that isn't working** is about the **view of metadata**

as the following example ( from our lab )

```
./kafka-metadata-shell.sh  --snapshot /var/kafka/controller/__cluster_metadata-0/00000000000000000000.log
Loading...
[2023-09-13 16:11:38,419] WARN [snapshotReaderQueue] cleanup event threw exception (org.apache.kafka.queue.KafkaEventQueue)
java.nio.channels.NonWritableChannelException
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.truncate(FileChannelImpl.java:399)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.FileRecords.truncateTo(FileRecords.java:270)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.FileRecords.trim(FileRecords.java:231)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.FileRecords.close(FileRecords.java:205)
        at org.apache.kafka.metadata.util.SnapshotFileReader$ShutdownEvent.run(SnapshotFileReader.java:195)
        at org.apache.kafka.queue.KafkaEventQueue$EventHandler.run(KafkaEventQueue.java:186)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

in rare cases is works as

```
./kafka-metadata-shell.sh  --snapshot /var/kafka/controller/__cluster_metadata-0/00000000000000000000.log
Loading...
Starting...
[2023-09-13 15:33:18,481] WARN [snapshotReaderQueue] cleanup event threw exception (org.apache.kafka.queue.KafkaEventQueue)
java.nio.channels.NonWritableChannelException
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.truncate(FileChannelImpl.java:399)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.FileRecords.truncateTo(FileRecords.java:270)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.FileRecords.trim(FileRecords.java:231)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.FileRecords.close(FileRecords.java:205)
        at org.apache.kafka.metadata.util.SnapshotFileReader$ShutdownEvent.run(SnapshotFileReader.java:195)
        at org.apache.kafka.queue.KafkaEventQueue$EventHandler.run(KafkaEventQueue.java:186)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jline.terminal.impl.exec.ExecTerminalProvider (file:/xxxx/controller/kafka_2.13-3.5.1/libs/jline-3.22.0.jar) to constructor java.lang.ProcessBuilder$RedirectPipeImpl()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jline.terminal.impl.exec.ExecTerminalProvider
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[ Kafka Metadata Shell ]
>> ls /
local  image
```

but on **99% tries** we **cant** get the Exploring of  Kafka metadata using metadata shell

we not understand if this is a bug on Kafka Kraft version or something else?

our kafka cluster details

```
openjdk version "11.0.11" 
3 brokers PID's 
3 controllers PID's 
kafka version - 3.5 ( kraft mode )
```

example from `kafka-metadata-quorum.sh` ( we run it on first Kafka node )

```
 ./kafka-metadata-quorum.sh --bootstrap-server xxxxxx:xxxxx describe --replication

NodeId  LogEndOffset    Lag     LastFetchTimestamp      LastCaughtUpTimestamp   Status
1       30368           0       1694623038767           1694623038767           Leader
2       30368           0       1694623038606           1694623038606           Follower
3       30368           0       1694623038607           1694623038607           Follower
33      30368           0       1694623038606           1694623038606           Observer
22      30368           0       1694623038606           1694623038606           Observer
11      30368           0       1694623038606           1694623038606           Observer
```

here the files under `__cluster_metadata-0` folder ( the meta data topic )

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root       43 Sep 13 12:09 partition.metadata
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     4772 Sep 13 14:12 00000000000000012930-0000000036.checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       10 Sep 13 15:06 00000000000000019468.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      154 Sep 13 15:58 quorum-state
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      202 Sep 13 15:58 leader-epoch-checkpoint
-r-------- 1 root root     4772 Sep 13 16:06 00000000000000026669-0000000084.checkpoint
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10485756 Sep 13 16:44 00000000000000000000.timeindex
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10485760 Sep 13 16:44 00000000000000000000.index
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2239162 Sep 13 16:44 00000000000000000000.log
```

here is **example of expected output** ( from apache documentation )

```
  > bin/kafka-metadata-shell.sh  --snapshot metadata_log_dir/__cluster_metadata-0/00000000000000000000.log
>> ls /
brokers  local  metadataQuorum  topicIds  topics
>> ls /topics
foo
>> cat /topics/foo/0/data
{
  "partitionId" : 0,
  "topicId" : "5zoAlv-xEh9xRANKXt1Lbg",
  "replicas" : [ 1 ],
  "isr" : [ 1 ],
  "removingReplicas" : null,
  "addingReplicas" : null,
  "leader" : 1,
  "leaderEpoch" : 0,
  "partitionEpoch" : 0
}
>> exit
```

Related links

https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/595020396

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

since we used the Kafka Kraft version 3.5 , we look on documentation on version 3.5.1 to find hint about maybe bug that was fixed that related to our problem , but from following list we not find anything that related

```
Bug
[KAFKA-15053] - Regression for security.protocol validation starting from 3.3.0
[KAFKA-15080] - Fetcher's lag never set when partition is idle
[KAFKA-15096] - CVE 2023-34455 - Vulnerability identified with Apache kafka
[KAFKA-15098] - KRaft migration does not proceed and broker dies if authorizer.class.name is set
[KAFKA-15114] - StorageTool help specifies user as parameter not name
[KAFKA-15137] - Don't log the entire request in KRaftControllerChannelManager
[KAFKA-15145] - AbstractWorkerSourceTask re-processes records filtered out by SMTs on retriable exceptions
[KAFKA-15149] - Fix not sending UMR and LISR RPCs in dual-write mode when there are new partitions
```

Comment: If the shell doesn't work as expected, I suggest creating a JIRA for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking on `https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/`   , They give example how to check the metadata as the following

```
> bin/kafka-dump-log.sh --cluster-metadata-decoder --files metadata_log_dir/__cluster_metadata-0/00000000000000000000.log
```

above option to set the `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.log` gives exception and not working well

But other option is working is to set the file/s -`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.checkpoint` instead of  `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.log`

Example

```
kafka-metadata-shell.sh --snapshot ..../__cluster_metadata-0/00000000000005727401-0000003391.checkpoint
Loading...
Starting...
[ Kafka Metadata Shell ]
>> ls /
image  local
>> ls /image
acls  clientQuotas  cluster  configs  delegationToken  features  producerIds  provenance  scram  topics
>> ls /local
commitId  version
>>
```